# Make cell reference between a row and columns with a jump between columns using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried before that make reference a row to columns/a column to rows. They are not perfect but they work. However, I have trouble when it jumps and I really need help.

[image]

My code doesn't return an error but only 1 cell has value "=".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you:

*added in factor that user needs reference to cells, not just cell values.

```
Sub Row2ColumnReferance()

Dim rRangeCopy As Range, CRangePaste As Range
Dim jump As Integer

'get input
Set rRangeCopy = Application.InputBox("Select Copy Range", "Transform", Type:=8)
Set CRangePaste = Application.InputBox("Select Destination Range", "Transform", Type:=8)
jump = Application.InputBox("Enter")

Dim cel As Range, intCnt As Integer

'place new cells
intCnt = 1
For Each cel In rRangeCopy
    CRangePaste.Cells(intCnt, 1).Formula = "=" & cel.Address(False, False)
    intCnt = intCnt + 1
Next

Dim intRows As Integer

'insert space
intCnt = CRangePaste.Rows.Count
For intRows = intCnt To 2 Step -1
    Range(CRangePaste.Cells(intRows, 1), CRangePaste.Cells(intRows + jump - 1, 1)).Insert shift:=xlDown
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: it works however two small things: 1.  I would like to have cell reference instead of value.  So it just link cell C6,C7,C8 to cell D1 ("=C6), D3("=C7"), D5(="C8") assume a jump of 2. There is a jump of started cell.   I appreciate your help.

Comment: the jump does not work. Now it makes reference a row to columns without any space (even I enter 10,20,30...).

Comment: works fine when I run it. are you entering a column / row range to be copied to that is equal in size to the original range. So if your original range is 7 columns, you are selecting a column with 7 rows?

Comment: Now I got it.  First time, I only need to select a cell to make it start with.  This I need to select a range.  Thank you very much.

Comment: you could definitely modify the code to handle that as well, which would make it an easier user experience, where they wouldn't have to think about how the ranges being exactly equal.

Comment: @One small question, how can make it just overwrite the current data instead of shift the cell down?

Comment: kind of confused on that...  'the place new cells part will overwrite data. if you want to loop the range again and overwrite the cell value, use the same syntax as that part.

Comment: What I meant is - if there are row that all contains value and I would like to change the value of cell A10, A20, A30, A40 by using enter=9.  Then other cells will be shifted down.

Comment: thank for the code.  Instead of Insert Space, I just need to change the place new cells at (intCnt * jump, 1) instead of (intCnt, 1). Thank very the help